# finite state machine verilog

Tags: verilog, fsm

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on how to go about coding a pattern fsm in Verilog that produces the 4 different patterns on 8 LEDs and the LEDs change every tick pulse.
I know that I should be using state register and combinational next state logic, but I'm not sure how to go about writing it.

I hope someone could provide an example.

Comment: What 4 patterns, and how do the LEDs change?  Are you saying there are 4 static patterns and you just display them sequentially with each clock pulse, or is it 4 dynamic moving patterns where the FSM change is triggered by a button or something?

Comment: yes, there are 4 buttons to trigger 4 different modes, each mode will trigger 8 LEDs to move in a pattern, i.e. left to right, right to left.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to provide an example without knowing every detail... But the simplest case can look something like a state machine with four states and asynchronous reset. States change on every raising edge of the clock. For every state, 7-bit of data is "driven" to the led (you can extend it to 8 LEDs no problem, just more typing):

```
module fsm_example(clk, reset_n, data);

   input wire clk;     // Clock input
   input wire reset_n; // Asynchronous reset (active low)
   output reg [6:0] data; // Data driven to seven-segment display...

   // Constant state enumeration
   localparam STATE_0 = 2'd0;
   localparam STATE_1 = 2'd1;
   localparam STATE_2 = 2'd2;
   localparam STATE_3 = 2'd3;

   // Current FSM state (up to 2 bits, enough to hold values from 0 to 3)
   reg [1:0] state;

   // Clock-driven state machine. Changes state on every
   // raising edge of the clock.
   always @ (posedge clk or negedge reset_n) begin
      if (!reset_n) begin
         state <= STATE_0;
      end else begin
         case (state)
           STATE_0: state <= STATE_1;
           STATE_1: state <= STATE_2;
           STATE_2: state <= STATE_3;
           STATE_3: state <= STATE_0;
         endcase
      end
   end

   // State to output data mapping.
   always @ (state) begin
      case (state)
        STATE_0: data = 7'b0111111; // 0x0
        STATE_1: data = 7'b0000110; // 0x1
        STATE_2: data = 7'b1011011; // 0x2
        STATE_3: data = 7'b1001111; // 0x3
      endcase
   end

endmodule
```

The code is pretty straight forward if you know a bit of Verilog. Hope it helps.